# Is it possible to add a primary key to a table from a PL/SQL block?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I Was Working in an exercise and this question popup to my mind is there a specific function in pl/SQL can add a primary key constraint or any kind of constraints in an existing table?

Comment: Well, its' not a "specific function in pl/sql", it is simply the normal DDL, but within pl/sql all DDL has to be executed as _dynamic_ sql, as demonstrated by @Littlefoot.  But I'd seriously question why you fell a need to do this in PL/SQL rather than simply issuing the requisite sql statement directly from sqlplus or SQL Dev.    Typically, executing DDL within a PL/SQL procedure is indicative of poorly thought out design and/or requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible? Yes, with dynamic SQL.

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> begin
  2    execute immediate 'alter table test add constraint pk_test primary key (id)';
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select constraint_name from user_constraints
  2  where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME
------------------------------
PK_TEST

SQL>
```